# Assembly Loop Calculation in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm currently working on some projects learning how to read loop iterations optimized in assembly and I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me how I calculate the number of iterations. I see where the loops are executed, but am unsure of the iteration count process I should should use to keep track. Would anyone mind looking over this assembly from some C code in x86-64 and at least suggesting methods for counting the number of iterations? Please keep in mind this is related to school work I'm doing so I'm not looking for answers, but the process involved with getting the answers. Thank you!

```
    0000000000400714 <loop_multi>:
    400714: 55                      push   %rbp
    400715: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    400718: 48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
    40071c: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    400723: eb 13                   jmp    400738 <loop_multi+0x24>
    400725: 48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
    400729: 8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
    40072b: 8d 50 ff                lea    -0x1(%rax),%edx
    40072e: 48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
    400732: 89 10                   mov    %edx,(%rax)
    400734: 83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
    400738: 81 7d fc a7 00 00 00    cmpl   $0xa7,-0x4(%rbp)
    40073f: 76 e4                   jbe    400725 <loop_multi+0x11>
    400741: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    400748: eb 13                   jmp    40075d <loop_multi+0x49>
    40074a: 48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
    40074e: 48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
    400752: 8b 10                   mov    (%rax),%edx
    400754: 83 ea 01                sub    $0x1,%edx
    400757: 89 10                   mov    %edx,(%rax)
    400759: 83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
    40075d: 81 7d fc 99 00 00 00    cmpl   $0x99,-0x4(%rbp)
    400764: 76 e4                   jbe    40074a <loop_multi+0x36>
    400766: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    40076d: eb 13                   jmp    400782 <loop_multi+0x6e>
    40076f: 48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
    400773: 48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax
    400777: 8b 10                   mov    (%rax),%edx
    400779: 83 ea 01                sub    $0x1,%edx
    40077c: 89 10                   mov    %edx,(%rax)
    40077e: 83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
    400782: 83 7d fc 03             cmpl   $0x3,-0x4(%rbp)
    400786: 76 e7                   jbe    40076f <loop_multi+0x5b>
    400788: 5d                      pop    %rbp
    400789: c3                      retq
```

Comment: If you see where the loops are, what's causing you problem? You can see the numbers in the `cmp` instructions, right?

Comment: I see the jump, which is what I'm assuming to be the loop executions. Then I'm curious how I count the number of iterations. Do I actually need to compute the assembly values in the cmp, cmpl, etc.?

Comment: Not much to "compute", unless you mean convert from hex.

Comment: That's what I meant. I'm asking because I don't know. Should I be converting the hex values? If so, in what parts of the code do I convert the hex values?

Comment: Huh? The cpu doesn't care it only sees binary. As to which base you want the answer in, is entirely up to you.

Comment: My goal is to calculate the number of iterations in decimal that happen and how to calculate that. That's what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: No answering allowed, apparently.

Comment: Do you have problems converting from hex? Do you know that `0xa7` is `167` in decimal? The iteration count is `168` because the loop goes from `0` to `167` inclusive. @harold did tell you that in his answer though ;)

Comment: No, it's not that, I was trying to find that values that identify the iterations. So, in the cmp, it seems that the immediate value represents the iteration count?

Comment: That's the comparison for the end condition. The iteration count depends on the start value (`0` here), the increment (`1` here) and the conditional (`<=` here).

Comment: So for example, I'm looking at address 0x40075d. The left immediate value is $0x99. Then is the number of iterations 0-99, 100 iterations? I'm trying to understand how you're identifying the process. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The initialization is at `400741`, with the increment and the condition just around your `cmp`.

Comment: You don't identify it like pattern, you read the whole code, reason about effects of each instruction and guess what it does in the "big picture". Some instructions will cause some part of code to execute multiple times, can be anything from simple counter starting at 0 and incrementing until `cmp` final value is true, through simple countdown counters (starting at value N and doing `jnz` after decrement) to obfuscated anti-tamper code where the code will [not] loop malignly  only when being run under particular debugger. Start with understanding all instructions, then figure out their reason.